# viz extension crashloop with Request failed error unauthorized connection on server proxy-admin

Tags: kubernetes, linkerd

I just tried to install Linkerd viz extension following official documentation but all the pods are in a crash loop.

```
linkerd viz install | kubectl apply -f -
```

[Linkerd-getting-started](https://linkerd.io/2.10/getting-started/)

```
r proxy-admin
[    29.797889s]  INFO ThreadId(02) daemon:admin{listen.addr=0.0.0.0:4191}: linkerd_app_inbound::policy::authorize::http: Request denied server=proxy-admin tls=None(NoClientHello) client=50.50.55.177:47068
[    29.797910s]  INFO ThreadId(02) daemon:admin{listen.addr=0.0.0.0:4191}:rescue{client.addr=50.50.55.177:47068}: linkerd_app_core::errors::respond: Request failed error=unauthorized connection on server proxy-admin
[    29.817790s]  INFO ThreadId(01) linkerd_proxy::signal: received SIGTERM, starting shutdown
```

The error appeared on Kubernetes cluster `Server Version: v1.21.5-eks-bc4871b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was the policy that come by default installation.

This authorizes unauthenticated requests from IPs in the `clusterNetworks configuration`. If the source IP `(<public-ip-address-of-hel-k1>)` is not in that list, these connections will be denied. To fix this, the authorization policy could be updated with the following:

```
spec:
  client:
    unauthenticated: true
  networks:
  - cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
```

The default policy missing the client part

```
    networks:
      - cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
```

To update the policy, get the server authorization

```
k get ServerAuthorization -n linkerd-viz
NAME           SERVER
admin          admin
grafana        grafana
metrics-api    metrics-api
proxy-admin    proxy-admin
```

Now edit admin,grafana, proxy-admin and grafana and add the `networks` part.

```
 k edit ServerAuthorization metrics-api
```

as after fixing this I was also getting errors for grafana which help me to fix by adding network part.

```
[    32.278014s]  INFO ThreadId(01) inbound:server{port=3000}:rescue{client.addr=50.50.53.140:44718}: linkerd_app_core::errors::respond: Request failed error=unauthorized connection on server grafana
[    38.176927s]  INFO ThreadId(01) inbound:server{port=3000}: linkerd_app_inbound::policy::authorize::http: Request denied server=grafana tls=None(NoClientHello) client=50.50.55.177:33170
```

[All linkerd-viz pods in CrashLoopBackOff](https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd2/issues/7233)